# :not() pseudo selector works incorrect with some tags

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

HTML:

```
<p>I`m p</p>
<a>I`m a</a>
<h2>I`m h2</h2>
```

CSS:

```
:not(p){
 color:red;}
```

:not() pseudo class should select all the elements inside the HTML document, that aren`t "p", and give them red color, but when i run the code "p" is red too, just like all other elements.

Comment: I think this:not() only will not work?  Where:not() ? Maybe h2:not(p){
 color:red;}

Comment: The selector matches the body tag and the color gets inherited. Try something like body :not(p)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notorious Zet you can fix this error by giving the p element a class and then using the not pseudo selector

The HTML

```
<p class = "notRed"> This is a p element </p>
<h1>This is a h1 element</h1>
```

The CSS

```
p:not(notRed){
color: red /*This will apply to all p elements with the class of notRed*/
}
```

Comment: we need to exclude all <p></p> elements. Why would we add class to it. this will make code ugly. instead set one color to all elements and add desired color to only necessary elements.

Comment: This will cause all `<p>` tag text color set to red. If you want specific `p` tag with class "notRed" not setting red, you should code like this: `p:not(.notRed)`.

Answer (score 2):

here you need to specify color for all html elements. as there is no color set to elements, the color from your selector is getting set to all elements available.

Here is what you need to add in your style:

```
*{
      color: black;/* the color you will want for all or p elements. */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to specify the color of `<p>` tag first. See the [example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_not) from w3schools.

```css
p {
  color: black;
}

:not(p) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p> I am p </p>
<a href="#"> I am a </a>
<h1> I am h1 </h1>
```